# Не считывается свойство объекта в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

В самом конце программы нужны удалить некоторые объекты, но в переменную b не записывается значение свойства endSrv

```js
var client = [];

client[1] = {
  intervalVhod: 5,
  intervalSrv: 11,
  input: 5,
  startSrv: 5,
  endSrv: 16,
};

console.log(client[1]);

for (var i = 2; i < 30; i++) {


  var intervalVhod = Math.floor(Math.random() * (7 - 2) + 2);
  var intervalSrv = Math.floor(Math.random() * (16 - 2) + 2);
  var startSrv;

  client[i] = {
    intervalVhod: intervalVhod,
    intervalSrv: intervalSrv,
  };

  var input = client[i - 1].input + client[i - 1].intervalVhod;


  if (input < client[i - 1].endSrv) {
    startSrv = client[i - 1].endSrv
  } else {
    startSrv = input
  };

  client[i].input = input;
  client[i].startSrv = startSrv;
  client[i].endSrv = startSrv + intervalSrv;


  console.log(client[i]);

}


for (var i = 2; i < 30; i++) {
  var a = client[i + 2].input;
  var b = client[i - 1].endSrv;
  console.log("i=",i," a=",a, " b=",b);
  if (a < b) {
    delete client[i + 2]
  } else {};
};
```

Comment: "в переменную b не записывается значение свойства endSrv" - как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: Браузер пишет cannot read property

Comment: Смотрите объяснение в ответе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы отпиливаете сук

```
delete client[i + 2];
```

на который собираетесь залезть через три итерации

```
var b = client[i - 1].endSrv;
```

*Update*

Вы можете собирать индексы элементов, которые надо удалить, в отдельный массив и потом пройти по этому массиву (с конца к началу), удаляя из `client` элементы на соответствующих местах, используя метод `splice` (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp). Или удалять сразу, но тогда надо помнить, что массив `client` будет уменьшаться в процессе того, как Вы по нему итерируете.

Даже если Вы ничего не удалите из `client`, Вас ждет неприятный сюрприз в конце цикла, когда Вы выйдете за границу массива: `var a = client[i + 2].input;` при `i = 28`.

Comment: Второй день мне помогаете, спасибо вам)
Но что-то теперь никак не могу придумать как удалять мне третий объект из очереди, если его input < endSrv[i-3]  ?

Comment: Уважаемый Егор,   var a = client[i + 2].input; данная строка все равно выдаёт ошибку в браузере, даже если я не удаляю элементы хром всё равно настаивает Cannot read property 'input' of undefined

Comment: @MatthewYakovlev Хм, Вы до конца прочитали мой ответ?

Comment: жуть как стыдно, что невнимательным оказался под конец сообщения(
изменил границу обхода массива и всё заработало, большое вам спасибо)

Comment: @MatthewYakovlev На здоровье. Успехов!